# Using groupingBy to calculate differences between adjacent list elements

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a list of already sorted objects `Round` and in the middle a field `beginDate`. I would like using `groupingBy` in stream (or another method if it's better) to
calculate the field `differenceDaysNumber` by differences of the field `beginDate` of the current element and the next element in the list, except that if the next element in the list has the same value in the field: and the larger field: `number`, then we rewrite this value to all copies.

Something like that, pseudocode:

```
1 ob1 (differenceDaysNumber: ob1.beginDate-ob2.beginDate)
2 ob2 (differenceDaysNumber: ob3.beginDate-ob2.beginDate)
3 ob3 (differenceDaysNumber: ob4.beginDate-ob3.beginDate)
  3.1 ob3  (differenceDaysNumber: ob4.beginDate-ob3.beginDate) //this is copy with the same differenceDaysNumberas ob.3
  3.2 ob3 (differenceDaysNumber: ob4.beginDate-ob3.beginDate)  //this is copy with the same durTime as ob.3
4 ob4 (differenceDaysNumber: null)
```

```java
@Builder
@Getter
public class Round {
    
    Integer number;
    LocalDateTime beginDate;
    @Setter
    Integer differenceDaysNumber;
}
```

```java
var result = seriesInfoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SeriesInfo::getStartTime));  //what next ?

//input
List<Round> input = List.of(
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12), null),
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), null),
        new Round(2, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), null),
        new Round(3, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), null),
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12), null),
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), null));

//expected result
List<Round> output = List.of(
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12), 10),
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), 6),
        new Round(2, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), 6), //it is a copy because it has the same date and a larger number than the parent
        new Round(3, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), 6), //it is a copy because it has the same date and a larger number than the parent
        new Round(3, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12), 5),
        new Round(1, LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), null));
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Round> output = input.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Round::getBeginDate))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(rounds -> {
        int maxNumber = rounds.stream().mapToInt(Round::getNumber).max().orElse(0);
        return rounds.stream().map(round -> {
            int differenceDays = 0;
            if (rounds.size() > 1 && round.getNumber() == maxNumber) {
                differenceDays = rounds.get(rounds.size() - 1).getBeginDate().getDayOfMonth()
                        - round.getBeginDate().getDayOfMonth();
            } else if (rounds.size() > 1) {
                differenceDays = rounds.get(rounds.indexOf(round) + 1).getBeginDate().getDayOfMonth()
                        - round.getBeginDate().getDayOfMonth();
            }
            round.setDifferenceDaysNumber(differenceDays);
            return round;
        });
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> The code uses groupingBy to group the Round objects based on the
> beginDate. Then, it iterates over the grouped values, calculates the
> differenceDaysNumber based on the specified conditions, and sets the
> value for each Round object. Finally, it collects the updated Round
> objects into a new list named output.
>
> The resulting output list will contain Round objects with the
> differenceDaysNumber field calculated according to the given
> conditions.